# How to get inline code ending with spaces with docutils/sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, docutils

The following rST directive doesn't support trailing spaces:

```
:code:`foo    `
```

Example:

```
>>> from docutils import core
>>> whole = core.publish_parts(""":code:`x    `""")['whole']
<string>:1: (WARNING/2) Inline interpreted text or phrase reference start-string without end-string.
```

Is there a way to get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  According to the [docutils documentation of Inline markup recognition rules](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#inline-markup-recognition-rules):

> 2. Inline markup end-strings must be immediately preceded by non-whitespace.